# How to connect to Alibaba Cloud cluster use kubeconfig

Tags: kubernetes, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I have created Kubernetes on Alibaba Cloud and would like to control from client, such as kube master master/nodes `kubectl`, `kubernetes-dashboard`, deploy (manifests) from local to cloud, etc without SSH.

I know that we can use `kubeconfig`, but no idea for it now, please help me more, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you created a cluster using kubeadm for example, you will need to enter the instance through SSH and download the kube-apiserver client certificates and CA from /etc/kubernetes/pki.

Once you have them, you can add the configuration to kubeconfig using these commands (based on https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/10-configuring-kubectl.md). Make sure you replace the IP_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_CLUSTER, CLIENT_CERTIFICATE, CLIENT_KEY placeholders (instead of admin you can choose another name for the credentials):

```
kubectl config set-cluster your cluster \
  --certificate-authority=CA_CERTIFICATE \
  --embed-certs=true \
  --server=https://IP_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_CLUSTER:6443

kubectl config set-credentials admin \
  --client-certificate=CLIENT_CERTIFICATE \
  --client-key=CLIENT_KEY

kubectl config set-context your-cluster-context \
  --cluster=your-cluster \
  --user=admin
```

If you get authentication errors, then you used the incorrect certificates.

In addition, make sure that you open port 6443 in your cloud firewall, otherwise you will not be able to access.